# How do i get the maximum number of concurrent executions,minimum and average in AWS lambda using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

How do i get the maximum number of concurrent executions,minimum and average in AWS lambda using boto3 and cloudwatch?

I don't know what should i put in dimensions,period etc.

```
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch',aws_access_key_id=awsaccesskey,
                      aws_secret_access_key=awssecretkey,
                      region_name=awsregion)

response = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(
    MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'string',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'AWS/Lambda',
                    'MetricName': 'ConcurrentExecutions',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            "Name": "FunctionName",
                            "Value": "benchmark-hl7"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 36000,
                'Stat': 'Average',
                'Unit': 'Bytes'
            },
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime(2015, 1, 1),
    EndTime=datetime.now()
)

print(response)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only notable issue in your code is that the **units are incorrect**. This will result in empty results. The correct unit is `Count`, not `Bytes`. Thus, it should be:

```
Unit': 'Count'
```

Also metrics retention is **15 months** so you will not get any result dating back to 2015.